# FFT Using Accelerate In Swift

Tags: swift, fft

I am trying to write FFT code in swift to match Matlab FFT code.

So far I notice that when "input.count" is equal to 2^n (where n = 1, 2, 3, ...), the results match perfectly well.

However, for arbitrary sample size ("input.count" is NOT equal to 2^n), Swift and Matlab results do not match.

I am pasting the code below with 2 simple examples.

```
 import Accelerate

 public func fft(_ input: [Double]) -> ([Double],[Double]) {

 var real = [Double](input)

 var imaginary = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: input.count)

 var splitComplex = DSPDoubleSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imaginary)

 let length = vDSP_Length(floor(log2(Float(input.count))))

 let radix = FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2)

 let weights = vDSP_create_fftsetupD(length, radix)

 vDSP_fft_zipD(weights!, &splitComplex, 1, length, FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

 return (real, imaginary)
 }

// 2^N samples (WORKS; Matlab Output Same)
let (rl, img) = fft([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
print("REAL:", rl)
print(" ")
print("IMAG:", img)
print(" ")
// Swift Real: [36.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0]

// Matlab Real: [36, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4, -4]

// Swift Imag: [0.0, 9.6568542494923797, 4.0, 1.6568542494923806, 0.0, -1.6568542494923806, -4.0, -9.6568542494923797]

// Matlab Imag: [0, 9.65685424949238, 4, 1.65685424949238, 0, -1.65685424949238, -4, -9.65685424949238]


// N samples (DOES NOT WORK; Matlab Output Different)
let (rl2, img2) = fft([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print("REAL:", rl2)
print(" ")
print("IMAG:", img2)
print(" ")
// Swift Real: [36.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, -4.0, 9.0]

// Matlab Real: [45, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5, -4.5]

// Swift Imag: [0.0, 9.6568542494923797, 4.0, 1.6568542494923806, 0.0, -1.6568542494923806, -4.0, -9.6568542494923797, 0.0]

// Matlab Imag: [0, 12.3636483875458, 5.36289116667395, 2.59807621135332, 0.793471413188091, -0.793471413188091, -2.59807621135332, -5.36289116667395, -12.3636483875458]
```

Comment: As pointed out in the comments and answers to the "duplicate", FFT from the Accelerate framework can handle only certain sample sizes (powers of 2, times 1, 3, 5, or 15).

Comment: Thanks Martin. So it seems there is no solution for now for arbitrary data size !

Comment: For an FFT size that does not have small factors, you can still use the Accelerate framework to do a matrix multiply by a DFT basis vector matrix.

Comment: Thanks hotpaw ! Actually I have already written a brute force DFT algorithm now that works well (results same as Matlab for arbitrary sample size) on small sample sizes. But say for large sample sizes (> 15,000), it takes about 20 s to compute which is too much. Perhaps Matrix multiplication (as you suggest) might be the way to go. I am creating another post seeking help on how to go to Matrix form DFT (I don't know much about it) or maybe speed up my brute force algorithm.